# Convert a vector of tuples in an array in JULIA

Tags: julia

I'm quite new to Julia and I'm trying to convert a vector of tuples in array.
Here's an example

```
using Statistics
a = randn((10, 100))
q = (0.05, 0.95)
conf_intervals = [quantile(a[i,:], q) for i in 1:10]
```

and `conf_intervals` is a `10-element Vector{Tuple{Float64, Float64}}`.

The expected result should be a `10×2 Matrix{Float64}`

I tried splatting `conf_intervals` with `[conf_intervals...]` but the vector doesn't change.

Thank you very much

Comment: It is more efficient to slice along columns than along rows in Julia. If you can, you should organize your data so you can do `a[:, i]` instead of `a[i, :]`.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a comprehension:

```
mat2x10 = [tup[k] for k in 1:2, tup in conf_intervals]
mat10x2 = [tup[k] for tup in conf_intervals, k in 1:2]
```

Or you can just re-interpret the same memory. This is more fragile -- it won't work for all vectors of tuples, e.g. `Any[(i, i^2/2) for i in 1:10]`. But for `Vector{Tuple{Float64, Float64}}`:

```
if VERSION >= v"1.6"
    reinterpret(reshape, Float64, conf_intervals)
else
    reshape(reinterpret(Float64, conf_intervals), 2, :)
end
mat2x10 == ans  # true
```

Edit: On Julia 1.9+, you can also use `stack(conf_intervals)`. Like the comprehension `mat2x10`, this make a new array.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `collect` to convert tuples to vectors, and then you can combine them:

```
julia> hcat(collect.(conf_intervals)...)
2×10 Matrix{Float64}:
 -1.59757  -2.10057  -1.4437   -1.32868  -1.10686  -1.41256  -1.5696   -1.67288  -1.51947  -1.72257
  1.24604   1.61692   1.77684   1.3599    1.90853   1.30831   1.10667   1.58356   1.56811   1.70685
```

If you need to transpose the result, add an apostrophe `'` end the end of the command